# How do you load a YAML file in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, yaml

I've relatively new to Vue and the web ecosystem as a whole.

I've been building a small app and decided that I wanted to use YAML to store data instead of JSON mainly so that I could use comments.

I tried both of these YAML parsers:

- https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml (attempted to install via NPM)
- https://github.com/edus44/vue-cli-plugin-yaml (attempted to install via the Vue GUI accessed with `vue ui`)

However both had the same issue when I ran `vue serve`:

```
 error  in ./assets/data.yaml

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> #im a comment
| foo: "hello"
| bar: "world"
```

I'm fairly certain this is valid YAML...here's what my YAML file looks like:

```
#im a comment
foo: "hello"
bar: "world"
```

Here is how I tried to import it:

```
import data from "./assets/data.yaml"
```

I tried following the instructions at the URL that the error pointed to (https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders) but was immediately lost because:

1. I don't have a webpack.config.js in my project (it was setup automatically for me via [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/))
2. The format `const path = require('path');` doesn't appear to work in a Vue project?

Both of the YAML parsers and the webpack page assume a lot of prerequisite knowledge that I don't have and further Googling as only confused me more :(

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a `vue.config.js` file to your project and read about [Adding a New Loader](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader).

Comment: I just added `vue-cli-plugin-yaml` to my vue project ... and everything just works out of the box - except I used `import data from "@/assets/data.yaml"` but that's just a path difference, so not relevant to any error you may be getting

Comment: @JaromandaX Hmm I just made a vue new project by doing `vue create test`, following default steps, then adding `vue-cli-plugin-yaml` via `npm install --save-dev vue-cli-plugin-yaml` but I still still see the same error :(

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I followed your link, but it seems to assume that I have some knowledge of the loader API? I don't even know what the methods used here do (e.g. what does the use() function do?). I attempted to just replace the relevant bits in the example, but ended up with the same error.

Comment: @SHiLLySiT could you share the output from `vue config inspect`.It is your current project configuration which contains some boilerplate which may or may not be present in your `vue.config.js` file and vue adds when your project is creaetd

Comment: @Eazash I updated my answer below with the pastebin link, but here is the link as well https://pastebin.com/rRgWdHca

Answer (score 5):

After fiddling with [vue-cli-plugin-yaml](https://github.com/edus44/vue-cli-plugin-yaml) for awhile, I gave up and tried [@DigitalDrifter's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831532/how-do-you-load-a-yaml-file-in-vue?noredirect=1#comment114624363_64831532) and read up on [Adding a New Loader](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader). However this page alone didn't have a ton of information on how to *use* the API, so I browsed vue.config.js files on Github until I could piece one together:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('yaml')
        .test(/\.ya?ml?$/)
        .use('json-loader')
          .loader('json-loader')
          .end()
        .use('yaml-loader')
          .loader('yaml-loader')
  }
}
```

As the vue.config.js file shows, I ended up installing [yaml-loader](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml-loader) and [json-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader).

However, this *still* didn't work. I tried for ages with different configurations of vue.config.js only to eventually discover that the file needs to live in my src folder, not the root of my project e.g. `project_folder/src/vue.config.js` *NOT* `project_folder/vue.config.js`.

However this seems to go against what [official docs say](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js):

> vue.config.js is an optional config file that will be automatically loaded by @vue/cli-service if it's present in your project root (next to package.json).

It also causes `vue inspect --rule yaml` to return `undefined` so I don't think this is a real solution but rather a workaround, so I won't accept this as the answer. Not sure if the docs are wrong, or if there's something weird with my environment. Its certainly not just this project as a fresh one had the same issues.

[Here are the results](https://pastebin.com/rRgWdHca) of `vue inspect`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked for me but I didn't need to move the `vue.config.js` file to the `src` folder. My setup wasn't working at first because I had switched the initialization between `json-loader` and `yaml-loader` but it actually has to be exactly how you've written down in your code (use `json-loader` first, then use `yaml-loader` next)

Answer (score 0):

according to [json-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader): Since webpack >= v2.0.0, importing of JSON files will work by default.

Thus just install and use [yaml-loader](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml-loader) should work (at least it work for me). Also you should modify `vue.config.js` like this:

```json
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('yaml')
        .test(/\.ya?ml?$/)
        .use('yaml-loader')
          .loader('yaml-loader')
  }
}
```